# How to design Protractor page object navigation to avoid "window.angular is undefined" errors

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am having trouble with "window.angular is undefined" errors and I'm sure it has something to do with the asynchronous execution of JavaScript, but I don't know how to get around that. The login page and the initial landing page are non-Angular pages and the rest of the application is Angular. So, I need to login using a non-Angular page, then once the non-Angular landing page loads, open a drop down menu and click a link that loads an Angular page. It seems that all the actions just fly on, none of them waiting for navigation to complete before checking whether Angular is loaded or not.

I have this base class for page objects:

```
export class AbstractLoadable {

    constructor(isAngularComponent) {
        this.isAngularComponent = isAngularComponent;
    }

    initComponent() {

        console.log("Initializing: " + this.isAngularComponent);

        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(this.isAngularComponent);

        if(this.isAngularComponent) {
            console.log("Waiting for angular");
            browser.waitForAngular();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

I have this login page:

```
import {AbstractLoadable} from "./AbstractLoadable";
import {HomePage} from "./HomePage";

export class LoginPage extends AbstractLoadable {

    constructor() {
        super(false);

        this.usernameInput = element(by.id("username"));
        this.passwordInput = element(by.id("password"));
        this.loginButton = element(by.css("[name='login']"));
    }

    load(baseUrl) {
        browser.driver.get(baseUrl);
        return this.initComponent();
    }

    login(username, password) {
        this.usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
        this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
        this.loginButton.click();

        return new HomePage().initComponent();

    }
}
```

I have this Home page:

```
import {AbstractLoadable} from "./AbstractLoadable";
import {LoginPage} from "./LoginPage";
import {AngularPage} from "./AngularPage";
import {ExtendedExpectedConditions} from "../ExtendedExpectedConditions";

export class HomePage extends  AbstractLoadable {

    constructor() {
        super(false);

        this.menuButton = element(by.id("some locator"));
        this.menuContainer = element(by.css("some locator"));
        this.menuOptionLink = element(by.css("some locator"));
    }

    isMenuButtonPresent() {
        return ExtendedExpectedConditions.isElementPresent(this.menuButton);
    }

    isMenuExpanded() {
        return ExtendedExpectedConditions.isElementDisplayed(this.menuContainer);
    }

    expandMenu() {
        this.isMenuButtonPresent().then(isPresent => {
            if(!isPresent) {
                ExtendedExpectedConditions.waitForElementVisible(this.menuButton, 120000)
            }
        });

        this.isMenuExpanded().then(isExpanded => {
            if(!isExpanded) {
                this.menuButton.click();
                ExtendedExpectedConditions.waitForElementVisible(this.menuContainer);
            }
        });
    }

    loadAngularPage() {
        this.expandMenu();
        this.menuOptionLink.click();
        return new AngularPage().initComponent();
    }
}
```

The wait methods are static utility methods in this class:

```
export class ExtendedExpectedConditions {

    static waitForElementPresent(element, timeout = 30000) {
        browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element), timeout);
    }

    static waitForElementVisible(element, timeout = 30000) {
        browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element), timeout);
    }

    static isElementPresent(element) {
        return element.isPresent()
    }
}
```

The angular page class has this constructor which passes 'true' to the base class constructor, indicating that it is an Angular page:

```
import {AbstractLoadable} from "./AbstractLoadable";

export class AngularPage extends AbstractLoadable {

    constructor() {
        super(true);

        this.loadDialogButton = element(by.css("some locator"));
    }

    loadDialog() {
        this.loadDialogButton.click();
        //This class also extends the base class and has a constructor that passes true to the base class constructor, indicating that it is an Angular component
        return new AngularDialog().initComponent();
    }
}
```

When I tried to execute this test, I keep getting "window.angular is undefined" errors:

```
import {LoginPage} from "../pageobject/LoginPage.js";

describe("Test", () => {
    it("Login and navigate", () => {
        let hp = new LoginPage().load(browser.baseUrl).login("user", "pass");
        let ap = hp.loadAngularPage();
        let dialog = ap.loadDialog();

        //isLoaded() checks visibility of dialog container element
        expect(dialog.isLoaded()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The console output is this:

```
Initializing: false
Initializing: false
Initializing: true
Waiting for angular
Initializing: true
Waiting for angular

Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

My package.json is this:

```
{
  "name": "ui-tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A description",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor conf.js",
    "start_selenium": "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "update_selenium": "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "es6"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

My conf.js is this:

```
require("babel-register");

exports.config = {

    framework: 'jasmine2',
    rootElement: 'body',
    seleniumServerJar:'./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar',
    chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.30',
    specs: ['tests/*Spec.js'],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--no-sandbox']
        },
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://www.myurl.com',

    suites: {
        login: '../tests/theTestSpec.js'
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 3600000,
        isVerbose: true
    },

    getPageTimeout: 120000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 3600000,
    delayBrowserTimeInSeconds: 0,

    onPrepare: function() {

        require("babel-register");

        let origFn = browser.driver.controlFlow().execute;

        browser.driver.controlFlow().execute = function () {
            let args = arguments;

            origFn.call(browser.driver.controlFlow(), function () {
                return protractor.promise.delayed(this.delayBrowserTimeInSeconds * 100);
            });

            return origFn.apply(browser.driver.controlFlow(), args);
        };

        let getScreenSize = function() {
            return browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
                return {
                    width: window.screen.availWidth,
                    height: window.screen.availHeight
                };
            });
        };

        getScreenSize().then(function(screenSize) {
            browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All protractor calls return promises. In your current code you create them but do not always wait for them to resolve. Everything that needs to happen after each other needs to be chained with the then keyword. [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

for example both of these checks are being done at the same time.

```
expandMenu() {
    this.isMenuButtonPresent().then(isPresent => {
        if(!isPresent) {
            ExtendedExpectedConditions.waitForElementVisible(this.menuButton, 120000)
        }
    });

    this.isMenuExpanded().then(isExpanded => {
        if(!isExpanded) {
            this.menuButton.click();
            ExtendedExpectedConditions.waitForElementVisible(this.menuContainer);
        }
    });
}
```

And here 'this' is returned immediately while browser.waitForAngular() is waiting asynchronously.

```
initComponent() {

    console.log("Initializing: " + this.isAngularComponent);

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(this.isAngularComponent);

    if(this.isAngularComponent) {
        console.log("Waiting for angular");
        browser.waitForAngular();
    }

    return this;
}
```

you will have to refactor your functions to return promises, so you can chain them one after another.